# How are the points in a level curve chosen in pyplot?

Tags: python, math, matplotlib

I want to know how the contours levels are chosen in `pyplot.contour`. What I mean by this is, given a function f(x, y), the level curves are usually chosen by evaluating the points where f(x, y) = c, c=0,1,2,... etc. However if f(x, y) is an array `A` of nxn points, how do the level points get chosen? I don't mean how do the points get connected, just simply the points that correspond to `A = c`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code (`contour.py`), it's something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.random.random((10,10))

pl.figure()
pl.contour(x, y, z)
pl.colorbar()

# manually calculate levels:
zmin = np.amin(z)
zmax = np.amax(z)

N = 7 # default
locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(N+1)
lev = locator.tick_values(zmin, zmax)

# Clip
levels = lev[(lev > zmin) & (lev < zmax)]

print(levels)
```

> [ 0.15  0.3   0.45  0.6   0.75  0.9 ]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function is evaluated at every grid node, and compared to the iso-level. When there is a change of sign along a cell edge, a point is computed by linear interpolation between the two nodes. Points are joined in pairs by line segments. This is an acceptable approximation when the grid is dense enough.